# python- mysql error when I use %s in execute

Tags: python, mysql, database, python-2.7

I have to delete some dates from mysql by python.
I have tables over 2000. so, I need to finish this code... I can't handle this much by clicking my mouse. I really need help.

well, my guess was like this

```
sql ="delete from finance.%s where date='2000-01-10'"

def Del():
for i in range(0,len(data_s)):
    curs.execute(sql,(data_s[i]))
    conn.commit()
```

Howerver, it doesn't work.

I just though
when I just type like this , it works.

```
>>> query="delete from a000020 where date ='2000-01-25'"

>>> curs.execute(query)    //curs=conn.cursor()
```

But if I add %s to the syntax, it doesn't work..

```
>>> table='a000050'

>>> query="delete from %s where date ='2000-01-25'"

>>> curs.execute(query,table)

ProgrammingError: (1064, u"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''a000050' where date ='2000-01-25'' at line 1")
```

it doesn't work too.

```
>>> curs.execute(query,(table))

ProgrammingError: (1064, u"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''a000050' where date ='2000-01-25'' at line 1")
```

a bit different... but same.

```
>>> curs.execute(query,(table,))
```

I have read many questions from here, but by just adding () or , it doesn't fixed... 
Because I'm beginner for the python and mysql, I really need your help. Thank you for reading.

Comment: The error message tells you, that your `table` var has been inserted into the string enclosed by quotes `'`. This is probably done by the `curs.execute()` function to avoid injection issues, but if you do it programmatically, you can format the string before passing it to the function.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I fixed by appending as:

```
def Del():
for i in range(0,len(data_s)):
    x = "delete from finance." + data_s[i] + "where date='2000-01-10'"
    print x # to check the sql statement :)
    curs.execute(x)
    conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Good question,have a look at [MySQLdb User's Guide](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#functions-and-attributes)

> **paramstyle**
>
> String constant stating the type of parameter marker formatting
>   expected by the interface. Set to 'format' = ANSI C printf format
>   codes, e.g. '...WHERE name=%s'. If a mapping object is used for
>   conn.execute(), then the interface actually uses 'pyformat' = Python
>   extended format codes, e.g. '...WHERE name=%(name)s'. However, the API
>   does not presently allow the specification of more than one style in
>   paramstyle.
>
> **Note that any literal percent signs in the query string passed to execute() must be escaped, i.e. %%.**
>
> Parameter placeholders can only be used to insert column values. They
>   can not be used for other parts of SQL, such as table names,
>   statements, etc.

Hope this helps.